# Horizontal form inputs are overlapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, forms

I'm having trouble getting a form to display properly.  The following two lines are displaying horizontally, but they overlap each other where name ends and email begins.  There's no CSS currently implemented on them, I've tried `padding-left`, `margin-left`, and a few other tricks but can't get them to separate.  Any ideas?

[image: Issue]

```
<div id="contact" class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
<div class="center hero-unit">
    <form action="success.html" method="GET">
            <h4> Contact Me </h4>
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" size="20" id="inline">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" size="35" id="inline">
            </div>
            </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Including CSS for the `hero-unit` just in case that's causing issues

```
.hero-unit {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #9C9C9C;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 30px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    border-color: #C1C1C1;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: `class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"` can be simplified to `class="col-xs-6"`. And `class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"` can be simplified to `class="col-sm-4"`. See https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E029

Comment: Have you tried the `form-inline` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add to the style:

```
.hero-input {
    padding:5px;
    margin: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

and to the inputs:

```
class="hero-input"
```

to have the margin and padding take effect on each input.  Obviously you can modify it to your own liking of padding and margins.  Basically the margins should either be in the input or the divs containing the inputs.  Also you should avoid using duplicate ids.  `id="inline"` should probably be `class="inline"` and if you use the extra hero-input class, then it could be `class="inline hero-input"`